# Using $.map i'm trying to put values into new array but is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is pretty simple,... but is not working. what am i doing wrong??

```
var oldArr = [0, 1, 2];
var newArr = [];

/*
 * The function adds 1 to each array el's value, unless the value is 0,
 * if so it deletes from array
 */
$.map(oldArr, function(n){
  n < 0 ? n + 1 : null;
  newArr.push(n);
});
alert(newArr) //show original values;
```

cheers everyone, thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The statement `n < 0 ? n + 1 : null;` in your code has no effect. It evaluates to `n + 1` or `null` depending on the condition `n < 0`. However, the resulting value is then simply discarded.

You either need to `return` the value as part of a call to `map` or `push` it onto the array `newArr` as part of an `each` loop. Examples of these two approaches are given below:

Using jQuery `$.map` (elements for which `n < 0` are removed from array):

```
var oldArr = [0, 1, 2];
var newArr = $.map(oldArr, function(n) {
  return n < 0 ? n + 1 : null;
});
```

Using `each` (elements for which `n < 0` are removed from array):

```
var oldArr = [0, 1, 2];
var newArr = [];
$.each(oldArr, function(n) {
  if (n < 0) {
    newArr.push(n + 1);
  }
});
```

If you wish to retain the elements for which `n < 0` and instead set them to `null` you would use the following approaches:

Using `Array.prototype.map` (elements for which `n < 0` are set to `null`):

```
var oldArr = [0, 1, 2];
var newArr = oldArr.map(function(n) {
  return n < 0 ? n + 1 : null;
});
```

Using `each` (elements for which `n < 0` are set to `null`):

```
var oldArr = [0, 1, 2];
var newArr = [];
$.each(oldArr, function(n) {
  newArr.push(n < 0 ? n + 1 : null);
});
```

Your original code is trying to do a hybrid of these two approaches. In summary:

- `map` means "return a collection each element of which is the return value from applying the supplied function to the corresponding element in the input collection":
- `each` is simple iteration over a given collection, executing the supplied function on each element in turn.

As @bfavaretto has pointed out previously, jQuery's `$.map` will remove elements for which the function returns `null` or `undefined` while `Array.prototype.map` will retain them. This leads to the major behavioural differences described above.

References:

- [`Array.prototype.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)
- [`$.map`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.map/)

Comment: jQuery doesn't seem to like it when you return `null` (it doesn't push null to the result, and simply ignores it).

Comment: OP explicitly wanted `n < 0` values to be removed, so I've updated my answer to describe both approaches.

Comment: Ah, I failed to see that in the question from the beginning, sorry.

Comment: No problem at all. I'm glad you noticed the major difference between `Array.prototype.map` and `$.map`. That's a subtlety I missed at first.

Answer (score 1):

When you `map`, you don't `push`, but `return` instead. Also, it looks like jQuery does not push a new value if you return `null` (or `undefined`)<sup>1</sup>. You could use [`Array.prototype.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) instead:

```
var newArr = oldArr.map(function(n){
    return n < 0 ? n + 1 : null;
});
```

Note that this will generate an array with 3 `null`s with your current input. Is that really what you're looking for?

---

<sup>1</sup> The [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.map/) actually says you should return `null` or `undefined` if you want to *remove* an item from the results.

Comment: For more details on Array.prototype.map: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

Comment: Thanks, I was being lazy; link inlined.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think `$.map` is what you're looking for here. `each()` would probably be better:

```
var oldArr = [0, 1, 2];
var newArr = [];

$.each(oldArr, function(idx, obj){
    if (obj > 0)
        newArr.push(obj + 1);
})
alert(newArr);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are the problems with what you currently have:

1. You're not setting `n` in the `$.map`, which is why the array is the same.
2. nothing in your array is less than 0

Here's how I would do this (assuming you want anything **greater** than 0 to not be null):

```
var newArr = $.map(oldArr, function(n) { return n ? n + 1 : null });
```